# AndEngine Box2D. Crash game after remove Joint with collides

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

Please help! My game crash after remove Joint with collides.

The game is the body that is hanging on the rope. Finger cut the rope, and the game crashes!

My code:

```
@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {

    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

    this.mScene = new Scene();
    this.mScene.setBackground(new Background(0, 0, 0));     

    this.mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);

    /* Create the face and add it to the scene. */
    ball = new Sprite(200, 50, this.mBallTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    ball.setScale(0.5f);

    final Rectangle point = new Rectangle(400, 0, 5, 5, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    rope = new Line(point.getX()+5/2, point.getY()+5/2, ball.getX(), ball.getY(), this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    this.mScene.attachChild(ball);
    this.mScene.attachChild(rope);
    this.mScene.attachChild(point);

    final Body ballBody = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, ball, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
    final Body pointBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, point, BodyType.StaticBody, FIXTURE_DEF);

    this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(ball, ballBody, true, true) {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
    super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
    final Vector2 movingBodyWorldCenter = ballBody.getWorldCenter();
    rope.setPosition(rope.getX1(), rope.getY1(), movingBodyWorldCenter.x * PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT, movingBodyWorldCenter.y * PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT);
    }
    });

    final RevoluteJointDef revoluteJointDef = new RevoluteJointDef();
    revoluteJointDef.initialize(pointBody, ballBody, pointBody.getWorldCenter());
    revoluteJointDef.enableMotor = true;
    revoluteJointDef.maxMotorTorque = 1;    
    final Joint joint = this.mPhysicsWorld.createJoint(revoluteJointDef);

    //collide detector
    this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {
        @Override
        public void reset() { }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
            if(rope.collidesWith(cutLine)) {
                mPhysicsWorld.destroyJoint(joint);                  
                mScene.detachChild(rope);
            } 


    }
});

    this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsWorld);
    this.mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);
    return this.mScene;
}

@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(final Scene pScene, final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {   
        if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
            this.addCuter(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
            return true;
        }           
        if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()) {
            this.moveCuter(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
            return true;
        }
        if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
            this.delCuter(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
            return true;
        }
    return false;}

private void addCuter(final float pX, final float pY) { 
    cutBegin = new Rectangle(pX, pY, 5, 5, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    cutEnd = new Rectangle(pX, pY, 5, 5, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    cutLine = new Line(cutBegin.getX()+5/2, cutBegin.getY()+5/2, cutEnd.getX(), cutEnd.getY(), this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    this.mScene.attachChild(cutBegin);
    this.mScene.attachChild(cutEnd);
    this.mScene.attachChild(cutLine);

    cutEnd.setColor(1, 0, 0);
    cutLine.setColor(1, 0, 0);}

private void moveCuter(final float pX, final float pY) {        
    cutEnd.setPosition(pX-5/2, pY-5/2);
    cutLine.setPosition(cutBegin.getX()+5/2, cutBegin.getY()+5/2, pX, pY);      }

private void delCuter(final float pX, final float pY) {
    this.mScene.detachChild(cutBegin);
    this.mScene.detachChild(cutEnd);
    this.mScene.detachChild(cutLine);}
```

Error LogCat

03-14 10:45:48.329: A/libc(12926): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)

Answer (score 1):

I find that this usually occurs when you try to alter some aspect in the game which the update is dependant on from an event firing, i.e., outside of an,

```
mActivity.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        //...                               
    }
});
```

Your onSceneTouchEvent looks like it may be a likely contender! Try adding the above code around the function calls which make changes to the scene to make it 'safe', i.e., you are not altering game variables from an interrupt while they are being processed by the update thread.